# "Vous êtes déjà griller" - correct?

Tags: grammaire

That's a phrase from the subtitles:

"Vous êtes déjà griller"

and my French friends say it is written grammatically correctly. Is it really?

Comment: No it is not. It should be “Vous êtes déjà grillés”.

Comment: Past participle vs infinitive, and how to do the agreement is a rule you learn around 8 or 9, still many adults struggle with it. I frequently read such errors in papers for example.

Answer (score 4):

Except for a trifle it is correct, but it is an important trifle in French grammar.

- Vous êtes déjà grill**é** ?

However, depending upon whom that is said to it could be different. It is assumed above that this is said to a man.

- (*to a woman*) Vous êtes déjà grill**ée** ?
- (*to several women*) Vous êtes déjà grill**ées** ?
- (*to several men*) Vous êtes déjà grill**és** ?
- (*to several persons of both sexes*) Vous êtes déjà grill**és** ?